# How can I sort the list by size?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am new here and new to Python.
I would like to know if anyone knows how to sort a generated list by size.

I have a piece of the code here. The sorting should be from small to large.
6.52, 26.4

```
for i in x:
    pfad = (i)
    title=(i)
    size = (i)
    bild = (i)

    liste=('<a href="' + pfad + '">' + title + '<br>;' + size + '<div><img src="' + bild + '" /></div></a></br>')
    print(liste)

    <a href="URL/">Title<br>;26.14;GB<div><img src="https://URL.jpg" /></div></a></br>
    <a href="URL/">Title<br>;6.52;GB<div><img src="https://URL.jpg" /></div></a></br>
    <and much more>
```

I tried with

```
liste = csv.reader(liste,delimiter=';')
liste = sorted(liste,key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for i in liste:
    print (i)
```

and other things (lambda and so on) but it did not work.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Greeting Tron

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. `I tried with... other things (lambda and so on).` Include in your question what you tried, it will help us. If you haven't done so already, check out _[the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)_ and _[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_.

Comment: You also might want to provide us sample input with expected output. This makes things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of getting just a simple list like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` then, using `sorted()` method is in ascending order by default, so no need of a key.

```
liste = csv.reader(liste,delimiter=';')
liste = sorted(liste)

for i in liste:
    print (i)
```

for descending order add `reverse = True` into sorting method.

You can retrieve an element from a list with `itemgetter()` like this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> z = ['foo', 'bar','qux','zoo']
>>> itemgetter(1)(z)
```

If still you want to sort with itemgetter you need to have atleast 2 dimensional list

```
>>> a = [[1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[4,5,7,8], [1,2,2,3,4,5,4,65,3,4,3,2,2]]
>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter(3))
[[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 65, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 7, 8]]
>>>
```

But I assume that csv reader will return a dictionary most probably

```
liste = csv.reader(liste,delimiter=';')
liste = sorted(liste, key=lambda k: k['name of the column'])

for i in liste:
    print (i)
```